# Java class for Max MSP- OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, string, out-of-memory, javax.imageio, max-msp-jitter

I am trying to use the following java in my max patch via an mxj (bridge between max and java). It is meant to download a jpeg stream from an IP address and render to a matrix. However, I keep getting a long list of errors, usually ending in an OutOfMemoryError at which point, my entire laptop will freeze up. The problem seems to be that there are too many strings being created and not deleted in time. I work with Max but have very little java experience. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

```
import com.cycling74.max.*;
import com.cycling74.jitter.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.net.*;

// created by bbn on Feb 18, 2005
/**
 * downloads an image from the web and outputs it as a matrix
 *
 * @author bbn
 */
public class v001imagedownloader extends MaxObject 
{

String imgURL="http://www.example.com";

JitterMatrix matrixFromUrlImage = new JitterMatrix(4, "char", 640,480);

public void bang()
{
    outlet(0, "jit_matrix", matrixFromUrlImage.getName());
}


public void downloadImage()
{
        getImage(imgURL);
}

public void getImage(final String someUrl)
{       
    (new Thread() {

        //public String url;


        public void run() {
            try {
                URL u = new URL(someUrl);
                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(u);
                JitterMatrix tempMatrix = new JitterMatrix(bi);

                 matrixFromUrlImage = new JitterMatrix(bi);                 

                // copy the temp matrix to the our matrix


                outlet(0, "jit_matrix", matrixFromUrlImage.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }).start();
}

public void setURL(String Url)
{
    imgURL=Url;
}

public void notifyDeleted()
{
    //getImage.release();
    matrixFromUrlImage.freePeer();
}
```

}

```
at v001imagedownloader$1.run(v001imagedownloader.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:214)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:319)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1367)
... 1 more
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1369)
at v001imagedownloader$1.run(v001imagedownloader.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:214)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:319)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1367)
... 1 more
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1369)
at v001imagedownloader$1.run(v001imagedownloader.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:214)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:319)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1367)
```

Comment: Put the whole stack trace.

Comment: Can you also output the URL you are trying to connect to at run time, inside the catch block? And make sure that URL is reachable from the environment where you run your program? The error message indicates a low level socket timeout. Maybe you are hammering the server faster than it can handle requests, ending in timeouts on the client side? If so, you might need to introduce some throttling mechanism. PS: I don't know Max, only Java, sorry. :-)